# Multiple different backgrounds in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, canvas, memory

I have millions of photos that I want to render all as a mosaic/ set as a webpage background in a grid form at the same time. How can I achieve it using javascript, jquery or any web technology without the browser crashing or slowing down?

What I tried:

1. Intended to create millions of span dynamically and set each picture as the background of a span: It slows the computer as it reached 60,000 spans.
2. Tried to use Div / Tables, even worse in performance than span.
3. Since the pictures can be created dynamically using javascript, I decided to draw each picture on a canvas, and draw as many canvas as possible, but still very slow.

Comment: **_I have millions of photos_**: you probably cannot.

Comment: Maybe stitch them together server-side.

Comment: Lazy loading maybe? you'll never have more than a few hundred images above the fold

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to show 60.000 pictures at 1 time,because i cant imagine that anybody will be able to see ALL 60.000 pictures at once.

what I would do is the following:

1 - generate a grid/span layout for the background of 5*5(or however many pictures you want to show at once);

2 - create a folder on the server with all images possible to use, with numeric increasing filenames like "0.png" "1.png" "2.png" "3.png" etc.

3 - IF you don't need the pictures to change while the user is looking at the page, and you will only change the pictures when the user is (re)loading the page, you can write a code on the server which generates a random number between 0 - max file numbers(-1). add ".png" behind that number and set that file as the background of the span.

3- IF you want the pictures to change while the user is looking at the page, you need to write a javascript code which will generate a random number between 0 - max file number(-1) . Add ".png" to that and change the background of a span to that filename. now repeat this function every x seconds.

this will prevent from creating 60.000 spans, which will definitely slow down the browser. Also you are not bound to  neither.

Answer (score 0):

According to your third point, ***the pictures can be created dynamically using javascript***.

So let's take your first idea of simply drawing it on a canvas, but instead of generating a lot of canvases, generate a single one, on which we will draw the full grid.

Instead of storing each picture as pixels, we'll just store what is needed to actually generate it. It will end up being just a bunch of coordinates, and with a bit of luck, we'll be able to store it in objects with similar enough shapes so that the js engines can optimize it in the best manner.

All we have to do then, is to calculate how many of these pictures can appear on our screen, place them in a grid, and render only the ones that are actually visible. (Since it is very unlikely you'll ever be able to render all these pictures at once).

```js
(function() {

  const pic_width = 150;
  const pic_height = 75;
  const padding = 10;
  const colors = Array.from({
    length: 150
  }, _ => '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 6));


  // This offscreen canvas is only used to avoid clipping the main one
  // It is shared by all instances of Pic
  const pic_drawer = Object.assign(document.createElement('canvas'), {
    width: pic_width,
    height: pic_height
  }).getContext('2d');
  pic_drawer.textAlign = 'center';
  pic_drawer.textBaseline = 'hanging';


  /* 
    Our Picture class.
    Holds only some coords in memory
    Redraws itself from scratch every time
  */
  class Pic {
    constructor(index) {
      this.id = index;
      const max_rad = 25;
      const min_rad = 3;
      // just hold some coords of points
      this.points = Array.from({
        length: Math.random() * 20 + 5
      }, _ => ({
        color: colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) | 0],
        x: Math.random() * pic_width,
        y: Math.random() * pic_height,
        r: (Math.random() * (max_rad - min_rad)) + min_rad
      }));
    }
    draw(ctx) {
      // render all our points on the small canvas so the clipping is easy done
      const pts = this.points;
      pic_drawer.clearRect(0, 0, pic_width, pic_height);
      pic_drawer.beginPath();
      pic_drawer.fillStyle = pts[0].color;
      for (let pt of pts) {
        if (pic_drawer.fillStyle !== pt.color) {
          pic_drawer.fill();
          pic_drawer.fillStyle = pt.color;
          pic_drawer.beginPath();
        }
        pic_drawer.moveTo(pt.x + pt.r, pt.y);
        pic_drawer.arc(pt.x, pt.y, pt.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      }
      pic_drawer.fillText(this.id, pic_width / 2, pic_height / 2);
      // draw back on main context
      ctx.drawImage(pic_drawer.canvas, 0, 0);
    }
  }

  /*
    The Grid instance will hold all our Pics
    It will get responsible for the main canvas' size and scroll
    And for the disposition of all our Pics and their rendering
    Exposes a *dirty*  flag so the outside anim loop can know when it needs update
  */
  class Grid {
    constructor() {

      this.dirty = true;

      this.scrollTop = 0;
      this.pics = [];

      this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

      window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize.bind(this), {
        passive: true
      });
      // ToDo: implement touch events...
      this.canvas.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.scrollTop += e.deltaY;
        if (this.scrollTop < 0) this.scrollTop = 0;
        this.dirty = true;
      }, {
//        passive: true // (disabled for SO's iframe)
      })

      this.resize();


    }
    resize() {
      this.width = this.canvas.width = innerWidth;
      this.height = this.canvas.height = innerHeight;
      this.dirty = true;
    }
    update() {
      // update only the grid info

      // number of columns that can fit in screen
      this.columns = Math.floor(this.width / (pic_width + padding * 2));
      // number of rows (ceil + 1 to get partial previous and next ones too)
      this.rows = Math.ceil(this.height / (pic_height + padding * 2)) + 1;

      const floating_row_index = this.scrollTop / (pic_height + padding * 2);
      const first_row_index = Math.floor(floating_row_index);

      // the index of the first Pic that will get drawn
      this.first_visible_pic = first_row_index * this.columns;

      // floating scroll
      this.y_offset = (first_row_index - floating_row_index) * (pic_height + padding * 2);
      // center
      this.x_offset = (this.width - (this.columns * (pic_width + padding * 2))) / 2;

    }
    draw() {
      const ctx = this.ctx;
      // clear
      ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
      // iterate through our cells
      for (let y = 0; y < this.rows; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < this.columns; x++) {
          // get the Pic at given index
          const index = (y * this.columns + x) + this.first_visible_pic;
          // in case it doesn't exist yet, create it
          if (!this.pics[index]) {
            this.pics[index] = new Pic(index);
          }
          // move our context at cell's coords
          ctx.setTransform(
            1, 0, 0,
            1,
            x * (pic_width + padding * 2) + padding + this.x_offset,
            y * (pic_height + padding * 2) + padding + this.y_offset
          );
          // draw our Pic
          this.pics[index].draw(ctx);
          // border...
          ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, pic_width, pic_height);
        }
      }
    }
  }


  const grid = new Grid();
  document.body.append(grid.canvas);

  function anim() {
    // only if it has changed
    if (grid.dirty) {
      grid.update(); // update the grid
      grid.draw(); // draw it
      grid.dirty = false; // clean the flag
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(anim); // check again at next screen refresh
  }
  anim();

})();
```

```css
:root,body,canvas{margin:0;padding:0;line-height:0}
```